# Pandas Dataframe timeseries

Tags: pandas, time-series

I want to build a dataframe with datetimestamp (upto minutes) as index and keep adding columns as I get data for each new column. For example, for Col-A, I aggregate by day, hour and minute from another dataset to a value 'k'. I want to insert this value 'k' into a dataframe at the 'right' row-index. The problem I am facing is the current row-identifier is from a groupby object on date,hour, min. Not sure how to 'concatenate' these 3 into a nice timeseries type.

This is what I have currently (output of my groupby object):

```
currGroupedData = cData.groupby(['DATE', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE'])
numUniqValuesPerDayHrMin = currGroupedData['UID'].nunique()
print numUniqValuesPerDayHrMin

Computing Values for A:
DATE      HOUR  MINUTE
2015-08-15  6     38        65
Name: UID, dtype: int64
```

To form a new dataframe to hold many columns (A, B, .., Z), I am doing this:

```
index = pd.date_range('2015-10-05 10:00:00', '2015-11-10 10:00:00', freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
```

Now, I want to 'somehow' take the value 65 and populate into my dataframe. How do I do this? I must somehow convert the "date, hour, minute" form groupby object to a timeseries obj...???

Also, I will have a series of values for Col-A for many mins of that day. I want to, in one-shot, populate an entire column with those values and fill the rest with '0s'. Then, move on processing/filling the next column.

Can I do this:

```
str = '2015-10-10 06:10:00'

str
Out[362]: '2015-10-10 06:10:00'

pd.to_datetime(str, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', coerce=True)
Out[363]: Timestamp('2015-10-10 06:10:00')

row_idx = pd.to_datetime(str, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', coerce=True)

type(row_idx)
Out[365]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

data = pd.DataFrame({'Col-A': 65}, index = pd.Series(row_idx))
df.add(data)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you almost got it figured out in your code. 
a few changes get the trick done.

1. initialize the dataframe without data and with the timeindex. (you
   can always append more rows later)
2. initialize the new column with values set to 0.
3. set the value for the column at the target time.

|

```
import pandas as pd


index = pd.date_range('2015-10-05 10:00:00', '2015-11-10 10:00:00', freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)

# initialize the column with all values set to 0. 
df['first_column'] = 0
# format the target time into a timestamp
target_time = pd.to_datetime('2015-10-15 6:38')
# set the value for the target time to 65
df['first_column'][ target_time]=65
# output the value at the target time. 
df['first_column'][ target_time]
```